# Get typeof keyof Object value of Context Provider React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have trouble while getting typeof keyof an Object as a value from provider.

```
<MyComponentProvider
  propProvide={{
     dataA: "10",
     dataB: "20"
  }}
>
   <ComponentChild propData="dataA dataB">
   </ComponentChild>
</MyComponentProvider>
```

How can I define the type  of propData based on keyof propProvide?

Thank you so much

Comment: this question is confusing, are you wanting help with the typescript typings? how do define a type that refers to the keys of `propProvide`? or are you trying to figure out how to send the values from `propProvide` to a child component?

Comment: @JohnRuddell yes your understand is right. I want to define the type for propData based on data value of provider

Comment: Is the data always going to be like `{
     dataA: "10",
     dataB: "20"
  }` . Can you define this outside and then create a type outside and then use props?

Comment: we need to know more of how the provider is setup to give a proper answer. where does the data stored under the key `propProvide` come from? hardcoded? from an API GET request? is the data model changing while using the app? please provide the code for your provider so we can help answer your question